# How to check file extension on Android

Tags: android

In my application, when we browse the file from the SD card, the files will be .text, .jpg and mpeg4ie video files.

I want to store each file type into a particular folder. For example, .text files go to the text folder.  When I select the file, how do I check the file extension?

Comment: Maybe this could be usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53869269/3894304

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I would get the file name as a String, split it into an array with "." as the delimiter, and then get the last index of the array, which would be the file extension. For example:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "image.jpg";
        String filenameArray[] = filename.split("\\.");
        String extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length-1];
        System.out.println(extension);
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
jpg
```

Comment: The point I am trying to get across is to not use regular expression for a simple task like this, not error checking.

Comment: What if I browse a file from the Gallery of my android phone, where it returns the file name as "content://media/external/images/media/3669". Can I get file name extension in that? @MikeLentini

Answer (score 48):

```
public static String getFileExt(String fileName) {
    return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length());
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the +1 part?

Comment: @RoCK Without the +1, it'd be, for example, ".jpg" instead of "jpg". Note the dot.

Comment: Can be simplified as fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).

Answer (score 18):

Or you could just do:

```
MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myfile.toURL().toString());
```

Note: this method is not very reliable though...

Comment: as File#toURL() is deprecated this should be myfile.toURI().toURL().toString()

Answer (score 14):

You can use [FilenameUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) from *Apache Commons*:

```
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(mFile.getName());
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also do something like the below and use endsWith.

```
public void walkdir(File dir) {
    String txtPattern = ".txt";
    String jpgPattern = ".jpg";
    String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";

    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            }
            else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(txtPattern)){
                    // Put in txt folder

                } else if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(jpgPattern.toLowerCase())){
                    // Put in jpg folder

                } else if (istFile[i].getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern.toLowerCase())) {
                    // Put in mp3 folder
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, I haven't checked the work, but it should do it for you.

Comment: Case sensitive extensions?  What about files called readme.TXT etc

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had a chance to run this (so it might not work 100%), but it should be what you're looking for:

```
File files[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
for (File f : files)
{
    String fullPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
    int dot = fullPath.lastIndexOf(".");
    String ext = fullPath.substring(dot + 1);
    if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("txt")) // Make sure case is irrelevant
                                     // for your use case; otherwise
                                     // use ext.equals("txt").
    {
        // Do something with f here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
public static String getExtension(String fileName) {
    String encoded;
    try { encoded = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20"); }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) { encoded = fileName; }
    return MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(encoded).toLowerCase();
}
```

When the file is `/mnt/sdcard/boomerang/2013-06-18_12:08:53.txt`, `"txt"` is returned.

Note the `URLEncoder.encode` and `.repalce` calls should fix any reliability issues you might see when `MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl` is called by itself.  For example, without the encoding and replace calls, file names such as `"Test Image!.jpg"` return empty strings.  Also make sure the file name is lowercased.  It `MimeTypeMap` does not seem to have entries for `.PNG` or `.JPG`.

Comment: `String ext = "", fileName = file.getName().toLowerCase();
try { ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fileName); }
catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` worked for me.

Comment: @zanky That does work a lot of the time, but there are cases (I forget which ones exactly -- it's been several month) where it fails unexpectedly.  In my experience, calling `Uri.encode` on the file name  drove the failure case down to zero.

Comment: @Xavi...ya, you might be right but in my case when i used `Uri.Encode` it was returning encodes extension of file which was having format something like this `3gp%4a%5D...` so i removed encode() method.

Comment: @zanky Huh, that's really weird.  I'll keep an eye out for that.  Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way to find out a file extension is using `lastIndexOf('.')`, assuming the file name contains an extension. Check the following code:

```
String fileName = "test.jpg";
int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
String fileExtension = fileName.substring(i+1);
Log.v("FILE EXTENSION: ", fileExtension);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a nice example at [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) on how to get the file extension that returns the file type extension in lower case or null if there isn't a file extension:

```
    /*
     * Get the extension of a file.
     */
    public static String getExtension(File f) {
        String ext = null;
        String s = f.getName();
        int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

        if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1) {
            ext = s.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase();
        }
        return ext;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Stuff is .endsWith("your extension"):

```
String whatever = you String;

if (whatever.endsWith("jpg")) {
    // Your jpg code
}
else if(whatever.endsWith("png")) {
   // Your png code
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Stuff is"*?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all of the files that have specific extensions in a certain directory:

```
File[] files = (new File("/sdcard/yourDirectory/").listFiles(new CustomFilter());

....


class CustomFilter implements FileFilter
{
    //Add the file extensions you want to look for here:
    private String[] extension =
        { "text", "jpg", "jpeg", "mpeg" };

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname)
    {
        String name = pathname.getName().toLowerCase();

        for (String anExt : extension)
        {
            if (name.endsWith(anExt))
            {
                // A file has been detected with that extension
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getExtension(File file) {
    String fileName = file.getName();
    try {
        if (fileName.contains("\\.")) {
            String filenameArray[] = fileName.split("\\.");
            extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length - 1];
        }
        else {
            extension = "dir";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        extension = "err";
    }
    return extension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that test all the cases

```
    String getExtension(String fileName){
        final String emptyExtension = "";
        if(fileName == null){
            return emptyExtension;
        }
        int index = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(index == -1){
            return emptyExtension;
        }
        return fileName.substring(index + 1);
    }
```