# Split string on the last occurrence of some character

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I'm basically trying to split a string on the last period to capture the file extension. But *sometimes* the file doesn't have *any* extension, so I'm anticipating that.

But the problem is that some file names have periods before the end like so...

```
/mnt/sdcard/OG Ron C, Chopstars & Drake - Choppin Ain't The Same-2013-MIXFIEND/02 Drake - Connect (Feat. Fat Pat) (Chopped Not Slopped).mp3
```

So when that string comes up it chops it at "02 Drake - Connect (Feat."

This is what I've been using...

```
String filePath = intent.getStringExtra(ARG_FILE_PATH);
String fileType = filePath.substring(filePath.length() - 4);
String FileExt = null;
try {
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(filePath, ".");
    String first = tokens.nextToken();
    FileExt = tokens.nextToken();
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
    customToast("the scene you chose, has no extension :(");
}
System.out.println("EXT " + FileExt);
File fileToUpload = new File(filePath);
```

How do I split the string at the file extension but also be able to handle and alert when the file has no extension.

Comment: Consider using `lastIndexOf()`, with some heuristics to detect when it denotes an "extension" and when it's part of the filename.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java

Comment: why don't reverse the string and take the first subString before the '.'?

Comment: may be this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894885/how-to-check-file-extension-in-android

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It might be easier to just assume that files which end with a dot followed by alphanumeric characters have extensions.

```
int p=filePath.lastIndexOf(".");
String e=filePath.substring(p+1);
if( p==-1 || !e.matches("\\w+") ){/* file has no extension */}
else{ /* file has extension e */ }
```

See [the Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) for regular expression patterns. Remember to escape the backslash because the pattern string needs the backslash.

Comment: The \w metacharacter is used to find a word character http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp

Comment: Note that this will fail on files whose names start with a dot and don't have an extension (e.g. `.gitignore`), which are pretty commonplace on POSIX-based systems. This can be fixed by changing the `if` condition to check if `p` is less than _or_ equal to zero.

Answer (score 69):

You can try this

```
int i = s.lastIndexOf(c);
String[] a =  {s.substring(0, i), s.substring(i)};
```

Comment: Note that this leaves the splitting character(s) in the beginning of the last string part.

Comment: Indeed, the answer should be: 
`int i = s.lastIndexOf(c);
String[] a =  {s.substring(0, i), s.substring(i+1)};`

Answer (score 7):

Is this Java? If so, why don't you use "java.io.File.getName".

For example:

```
File f = new File("/aaa/bbb/ccc.txt");
System.out.println(f.getName());
```

Out:

```
ccc.txt
```

Comment: too expensive to build a File object just to parse the name

Comment: seriously @jasmeet? Files don't do anything under the covers except parse the name; some methods you may call on them might be expensive, but the constructor is pretty cheap.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You can also call f.getParent() to get the path portion.

Comment: No, this should definitely not be the accepted answer, read the first line in the question:

"I'm basically trying to split a string on the last period to capture the file extension."

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your regex to ensure it only splits on the last occurrence.  The positive lookahead ensures that it only splits when it does not see another occurrence later in the string.

```java
// Using example filePath from question
String filePath = "/mnt/sdcard/OG Ron C, Chopstars & Drake - Choppin Ain't The Same-2013-MIXFIEND/02 Drake - Connect (Feat. Fat Pat) (Chopped Not Slopped).mp3";
String[] parts = filePath.split("\\.(?=[^.]*$)");
// parts = [
//     "/mnt/sdcard/OG Ron C, Chopstars & Drake - Choppin Ain't The Same-2013-MIXFIEND/02 Drake - Connect (Feat. Fat Pat) (Chopped Not Slopped)"
//     "mp3"
// ]
```

Breaking down the regex:

- `\\.` - Find a period
- `(?=[^.]*$)` - make sure everything after is **not** a period, without including it in the match)

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringUtils from apache commons, which is an elegant way of extracting file type.

```
    String example = "/mnt/sdcard/OG Ron C, Chopstars & Drake - Choppin Ain't The Same-2013-MIXFIEND/02 Drake - Connect (Feat. Fat Pat) (Chopped Not Slopped).mp3";
    String format = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(example, ".");
    System.out.println(format);
```

Program will print "mp3" in the console.

Answer (score 1):

How about splitting the filPath using the period as separator. And taking the last item in that array to get the extension:

```
        String fileTypeArray[] = filePath.split(",");
        String fileType = "";
        if(fileTypeArray != null && fileTypeArray.length > 0) {
          fileType = fileTypeArray[fileTypeArray.length - 1];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary splitting string `c` of any length:

```
int i = s.lastIndexOf(c); 
String[] a =  {s.substring(0, i), s.substring(i+c.length())};
```